# Create multiple configmaps on kubernetes with using helm from a directory that contains multiple files

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap

I have a few JSON files containing some config data in the directory path "src/Data".

I want to read each JSON file name and file data while Helm deploying and I want to create ConfigMap for each JSON file, the JSON filename should be the ConfigMap name and if the filename contains uppercase letters, then we need to use lower or something else to convert the name to lowercase and use that lowercase name to create ConfigMap

My release name is testdb which will read from values.yaml

The file names are below located at "src/Data":

```
adminMain.json
userAdmin.json
CreateUser.json
createRole.json
mainUser.json
```

Now when I run the helm command to create ConfigMap, it has to create the ConfigMaps as below with the data corresponding JSON file data

```
testdb-adminmain-configmap
testdb-useradmin-configmap
testdb-createuser-configmap
testdb-createrole-configmap
testdb-mainuser-configmap
```

I have tried below ConfigMap yaml, but there is no luck

```
{{- $files := .Files.Glob "src/data/*.json" }}
{{- range $file := $files }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}{{ lower $file.Base }}-configmap
  namespace: user-dev
data:
  {{ .Files.Get $file.Path | b64enc | quote }}: ""
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

If someone has any idea on this

Comment: What errors are you getting? You may need a `---` separator line at the top of your template so they don't all run together.

Comment: configmap itself not creating, I have tried below one also, but still not working

```
{{- if .Values.app.ConfigMapEntry.enable }}
{{- $files := .Files.Glob "src/data/*.js" }}
{{- range $file := $files }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ printf "%s-%s-configmap" .Release.Name $file.Base | trunc 63 | lower }}
  namespace: {{ .Values.app.namespace }}
  labels:
{{ include "test.labels" . | indent 4 | nindent 2 }}
data:
  {{ $file.Base }}.js: |-
{{ .Files.Get $file.Path | indent 4 | nindent 2 }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

Comment: See my previous comment. Add a line with just `---` above `apiVersion: v1`. And you didn't tell me what error messages you are seeing.